# Using google apps script to manage a google site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sites

I have been playing around with the Sites Services in GAS lately. I was hoping that there would be a way to add or edit embedded spreadsheets and charts. However, I have found the Sites services to be very limited. I have looked and am still wrapping my head around the Google charts API but I do not think this is geared towards integrating with a Google site.

My question is first, is it possible with the current services and if so what is a good starting point?

Thanks for any and all advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding embedding charts - see this [blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/09/visualize-your-data-charts-in-google.html) - particularly the code snippet around `addHostedAttachment`

Couple of other resources in the developer docs that might be useful around sites examples -

- [This tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/helpdesk_tutorial#section5) contains examples on how you can push list items from a spreadsheet to a Google Site.
- [Another tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/building-sites-app-part1#section5) shows how you can embed UI into a Google Site. You can use the same technique to embed chart.

Comment: Awesome! The first link is especially helpful.